# How do you calculate voltage drop in a neutral wire?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I've seen people saying that in practical situations, the voltage between the neutral wire and the ground is not exactly zero, is it true? And if yes, how do you find the voltage drop between these two?Assume an 120VAC and a 10 Ohms wire

Comment: *"Assume an 120VAC and a 10 Ohms wire"* - have you left out anything for this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

14 gauge wire has a resistance of about 2 ohms per thousand feet, your kettle might have 10 ohms.  So at 120volts you have 10 amps and 20v across the 1000 ft wire and 100volts across the kettle.